# Marketing Cloud Query - Failure: Cannot Insert a NULL value into a non-nullable column

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I've got a target DE with the following data privileges:

- ContactId = PRIMARY KEY
- Email = Nullable
- FirstName = Nullable
- HomeStore = Nullable
- State = Nullable

I am currently running this query and am resulting in the error message "Cannot insert a NULL value into a non-nullable column. What is interesting is we have several versions of this query for different lists we use and the only thing that is different is the Department__c and Class__c categories.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Query:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your 'OR' statement for *Department__c* needs to be grouped together, as it's evaluating the OR statements in line with the AND statments. For example:

> ContactID__c IS NOT NULL OR (Department__c = '2' AND Class_c = 'A')

In the statement above null values are considered valid for *ContactID__c* if the second part of the expression is true.

Try an extra pair of parentheses before the first and after the last department/class comparisons.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, I put quotes around the first like of Department & Class and that didn't work but when I added the second level of parentheses around the at large OR process it functioned perfectly. Thank you so much!